# Android ListView: Header/Footer that fills the remaining space on screen

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to make a chat-like view using ListView where the new messages appear at the bottom of the screen (therefore I use android:stackFromBottom="true") and I want to add a header to the ListView which will appear at the top of the screen. When there are few messages there will be an empty space between the header and the messages, when there a lot of messages, the ListView will be scrollable and the header will be hidden, when the bottom messages are visible (the header will scroll along with the rest of the messages).
The problem is that I can't tell the ListView to let it's headers or items fill the remaining space on the screen. android:layout_height="fill_parent" doesn't help. I can make the header static using RelativeLayout, but I don't want to. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put the list view in a table layout with 3 rows.  Put the listview in the middle row then use the top and bottom row as the header and footer.

Comment: What Marcos said will work but I prefer the table layout.  You could set your header and footer to a fixed height (in dip) and allow the listview to shrink/grow in height based on device being used.

Comment: Same as with Marcos's answer. I really need this Header to scroll along with the ListView, when the empty space is filled. I've seen it on iPhone but not yet on Android so I don't know whether is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LinearLayout on vertical with the header at top, your ListView in the middle with layout_weight="1" and then your footer.

One solution if you want the Header to be scrollable.
Is to inflate the position 1 in your adapter being the header you want to scroll.

Comment: But when I scroll the ListView the header will remain visible. As I said the case is a bit more problematic - I want the header on top, when there are not enough messages (and the messages are at the bottom), but when the space is filled with messages and the ListView becomes scrollable, I want the header to scroll along with the ListView.

Comment: Hmmm.. it's a bit more complicated. Check my new answer.

Comment: Thank you for keep answering me! I still don't know how to place the header on top of the screen (align it with top of the screen) and place the rest of the items on the bottom when there is not enough content to fill in the ListView. Making some hard-core calculations in the code is possible solution, but I'm looking for a smarter way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a different layout such as header_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/listitem_background"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dip" android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/nearByLabel" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Load More Results" 
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

And in your activity add it like

```
View headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_list, null);
yourlistView.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that was not the question. The way I have solved mine for now is to put the header at the top of the screen and when the first list item is not visible anymore to hide it with animation.